# Display a video pub into a popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with my divs, So I have a view cal game.php :

```
<div id="bonus-pub" class="not-display">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//scriptforVideoPub.php" defer async></script>
    <div id="videoPub">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have another view which is displayed as a window popup :

```
<section id="gameCoreModalContent" class="generique">
</section>
```

Now I want to show the pub from `<div id="bonus-pub">` in the popup
I tried :

```
<script>
  $( "#bonus-pub" ).appendTo( $( "#gameCoreModalContent" ) );
  document.getElementById('bonus-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
  pubFunction.show();
</script>
```

But the video pub is not displayed. If I remove `$( "#bonus-pub" ).appendTo( $( "#gameCoreModalContent" ) );` the pubVideo is diplayed out of popup. Help me please!! Thx in advance! Exist a solution?

Comment: Are you sure your `gameCoreModalContent` and `generique` CSS rule has not hidden the container `section`?